# Lombok hashCode:: 1. Why good? 2. Why no compile error?

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have the following simple Java code,

```java
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Test{
}
```

When I look at the delomboked code generated I see the following:

```java
public class Test {
    public Test() {
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(o instanceof Test)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Test other = (Test)o;
            return other.canEqual(this);
        }
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Test;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = true;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I don't understand the implementation of the `hashCode()`. How is this a good hashing method? And why is there no compile problem with `int result = true;`?

I suspect this is related to `hashCode()` being `native`, but I don't understand why I see this implementation.

---

**UPDATE:** My main question is in regards to the lack of compile error. If I add two fields for example I would have:

```java
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Test{
    private String name;
    public int age;
}
```

and

```java
...

public int hashCode() {
        int PRIME = true;
        int result = 1;
        int result = result * 59 + this.age;
        Object $name = this.name;
        result = result * 59 + ($name == null ? 43 : $name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

...
```

Comment: Did you check, what happens to the hashCode method, when you add state to your class (i.e. fields)?

Comment: Why would result=true be a compiler issue?  It's not illegal to have a pointless variable.  It's a warning at most.  As for why it does it at all-  most likely it would be used if you had actual fields, and they didn't bother special casing it to be removed for fieldless classes.

Comment: @GabeSechan Because the declared variable is `int` and `true` is `boolean`, and in java, unlike C(++) they don't match. Am I wrong? (I checked this before posting and I got a compile error.)

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That you see the `hashCode()` method like this is probably an artifact of the tool you use to analyze the generated bytecode.

Internally the boolean values `true` and `false` are represented by the values 1 and 0 respectively. Some bytecode decompilers blindly translate 0 into false and 1 into true - this is what seems to be happening in your case.

The `hashCode()` method should read as

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;
    return 1;
}
```

Now to the question:

**Is this a valid hashCode implementation?**

Sure it is. The contracts for `equals()` and `hashCode()` state that for any two objects `o1` and `o2` when `o1.equals(o2)` is true then it must also be that `o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()`.

Lomboks `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation generates code so that two objects having the same field values are deemed equal (and therefore must have the same hashCode).

Since your class doesn't have any fields, **all** instances are considered equal and therefore must have the same hashCode. The actual value of the hashCode doesn't matter, as long as it is the same value for all instances.

---

Is the code that you see an error in the decompiler?

Yes, it clearly is (because the decompiler generates invalid source code).

Lombok itself contains an integrated "delombok" feature (https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) and that feature creates for your first Test class the following source code (using Lombok 1.18.22):

```
public class Test {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Test)) return false;
        final Test other = (Test) o;
        if (!other.canEqual((Object) this)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof Test;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int result = 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you say the decompiler has a bug? Or, for instance, it is just not detectable when to use `1` and when to use `true`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your `Test` class doesn't have any field. So all instances of the class would be considered "equal" when using `@EqualsAndHashCode`. So the delomboked implementation reflects that.